# We're sorry, but something went wrong. - Heroku Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pg, sqlite3-ruby

I wanted to try Heroku as a hosting method. I can go to the home page, but when I press "Sign Up" I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message.

Is there any way of using sqlite3 instead of Postgres? If not on Heroku, then maybe on some different hosting service?

I watched the logs but cannot see the issue there.

```rb
default: &default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I just get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error message

Please go to https://crassar.herokuapp.com and watch it your self

Comment: So you have viewed what happens using `heroku logs --tails` ?  Also, I went to the sign up url and it displayed the page, is it when you fill out the form and submit it?

Comment: It's `--tail` not `--tails`, but yes, you need to check your server-side logs.

Comment: I can view the logs, [View It Here](https://imgur.com/en9ADtS)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `Heroku Postgres` add-on. It's free for Hobby Dev.
2. Get postgres (database) **url** from `Heroku Postgres`
3. Add url to config vars on Heroku, like this: (Settings -> Reveal Config Vars)

   ```
   variable name: DATABASE_URL
   value: postgres://blabla
   ```
4. Edit database.yml for production

   ```
   production:
     <<: *default
     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
   ```

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity, but I installed the add-on. I do not understand what I should do here "Get postgres (database) url from Heroku Postgres". And the point 3 was already set from default. I got the same problem, when I goto Sigup I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page.